# Swift Compilation Error for Property Wrappers with Codable in multiple files

Tags: swift, codable, property-wrapper

Compilation failed for property wrappers with codable in multiple files.

I found test codes in Swift source below:

- [property_wrappers_codable_multifile_other.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/decl/protocol/special/coding/Inputs/property_wrappers_codable_multifile_other.swift)

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Printed<Value: Codable>: Codable {
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        didSet { print(wrappedValue) }
    }
}

struct Foo: Codable {
    @Printed var bar: Bool = false
}
```

- [property_wrappers_codable_multifile.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/decl/protocol/special/coding/property_wrappers_codable_multifile.swift)

```
func test(_ value: Foo = Foo()) {
  let _: Codable = value
}
```

and use them in my test project:

[TestProject](https://github.com/wxindfx/TestPropertyWrapper)

But compilation failed with error:

```
Type 'Foo' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of visibility... the simplest fix is just to move those helper structs into `ViewController` module as below... run, and all works (tested with Xcode 11.2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The test Foo struct is not necessary to be Codable.

The test is on the `bar` property. and a Bool type is already  comformed to Codable.

```
struct Foo{
    @Printed var bar: Bool = false
}

func test(_ value: Foo = Foo()) {
   var m = value
   m.bar = true. // will call didSet in @printed struct
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I want to use property wrapper with codable, it should be a simple ablity. And I found test codes in swift source in github, but it can't be compiled.

Comment: You need to understand the definitions of protocol before you continue.

Answer (score 0):

Allow `test` to accept a generic `Codable` if that is the only requirement for that function:

```
func test<T: Codable>(_ value: T) {
    let val = value
}
```